# Control newlines in XML formatting with Grails render command

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

For most of our REST services, we are using the automatic marshalling of XML to output our results. Our testing group is reporting that they are getting unexpected new lines in the results (see below). I believe that these two results are equivalent considering that the only difference is ignorable whitespace and that testing should be parsing the results as XML and not doing string comparisons. Regardless, my personal preference would be to render the cleaner tighter version of the XML that testing wants, but my practical side says leave it alone.

I've done some digging into the Grails [render](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) command, but don't see any way of controlling this output. I would expect that there would be something that we could setup in Config.groovy to control this as well, but I can't find anything there either. Any suggestions?

We are getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profile id="45">
  <management id="6"/>
  <name>
    TESTING_MGT_DOC
  </name>
  <type>
    MGT
  </type>
  <user id="43"/>
</profile>
```

Testing is expecting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profile id="45">
   <management id="6"/>
   <name>TESTING_MGT_DOC</name>
   <type>MGT</type>
   <user id="43"/>
</profile>
```

We are producing these results from a simple, one-line call in our controller.

From ProfileController.groovy

```
...
if(param.name){
    render profileService.getProfileByName(param.name) as XML
}
...
```

From ProfileService.groovy

```
...
def getProfileByName(def name){
    return Profile.findByProfileName(name)
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only configuration that Grails have for that is `grails.converters.xml.pretty.print`. According to your output it seems to be set as `true`.

Looking at Groovy, it seems that `XmlUtil.serialize()` will format the way that you need. So go back to false in the Config.groovy, and change your controller to:

```
String xml = profileService.getProfileByName(param.name) as XML
render contentType: 'application/xml', text: XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

Comment: A `grails.converters.xml.pretty.print` entry was added to `Config.groovy` to address an issue in some of our demos that needed a "friendlier" XML display. I missed this change in my review of the file.

Once I reverted this, there was no need to make any further changes to the controller. 

Thanks!